# Get computer name and appear it using showmessage in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use this code

How do i make it appear in my screen, as a message?

```
Function GetUserFromWindows:String;    
Var    
  UserName : string;   
  UserNameLen : Dword;    
Begin    
  UserNameLen := 255;  
  SetLength(userName, UserNameLen) ;   
  If GetUserName(PChar(UserName), UserNameLen) Then     
    Result := Copy(UserName,1,UserNameLen - 1)       
  Else     
    Result := 'Unknown';      
End;
```

Comment: Computer name or user name?

Comment: It's like the title is asking for Apples, but the question body is asking for Oranges. Sure, they're both fruit, but not the same one.

Comment: Actually "appear it on the screen" is most vague part. Did an OP at least try to search before asking a question?

Comment: `ShowMessage(GetUserFromWindows);` OP answered their own question right in the title.

Answer (score 13):

Your function is wrong, to start with:

```
function GetUserFromWindows: string;
var
  iLen: Cardinal;
begin
  iLen := 256;         // UNLEN constant in LMCons.h says 256 - hard coded.
  Result := StringOfChar(#0, iLen);
  GetUserName(PChar(Result), iLen);
  SetLength(Result, iLen);
end;
```

If you actually want the *computer name*, as your question title says, it's not much different:

```
function GetComputerNameFromWindows: string;
var
  iLen: Cardinal;
begin
  iLen := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;         // From Windows.pas
  Result := StringOfChar(#0, iLen);
  GetComputerName(PChar(Result), iLen);
  SetLength(Result, iLen);
end;
```

Now you can use either of them anywhere you like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GetUserFromWindows);
  ShowMessage(GetComputerNameFromWindows);
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := GetUserFromWindows;
  Label2.Caption := GetComputerNameFromWindows;
end;
```

Comment: That constant goes with computer name, but you then ask for user name. No need to use StrLen since function returns how many chars copied. Question is terribly confused though.

Comment: @David, you're right. Fixed. (Ages old code I grabbed; didn't notice.) Thanks. You're right about the question being somewhat confused, though; that's why I addressed both issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'd still sooner see versions without StrLen but that's minor.

Comment: @David: I'm not sure why you object to `StrLen` in this case; it's just finding the actual length of the returned buffer and adjusting the length of `Result` to the proper size. I suppose a separate variable and then an assignment to `Result` would remove that, but it requires a separate string or char array allocation. (Not arguing - just asking why.)

Comment: The functions return the length seems pointless to work it out when you are told the answer.

Comment: Actually, pre-filling buffer with zeroes is as pointless as recomputing length with StrLen was. Actually, it is remnant of StrLen version. Simple allocation with SetLength is enough.

Comment: @user539484: Thanks, but I'll leave the initialization of the buffer as-is. I don't like using uninitialized local variables, and I'll accept the overhead of pre-filling it with zeros. If my code ever gets too slow, and a profiler says that wasted function call is the reason for it, I'll remove it. :-)

Comment: Hmm, it will never get too slow, unless someone will want to retrieve the same string endlessly. To prevent "uninitialised scenario", simply check API return value. By the way, which profiler is smart enough to sense that?

Comment: @user539484: My point exactly. It will never get too slow, so leave it alone. Removing it is an unnecessary optimization. It's not hurting anything. AQTime and other high-end profilers can analyze code at that level, BTW, to spot bottlenecks.

Comment: @user2242090: You might [edit] your question to make it more clear what you were asking, so people who find it in a search later can see if it also solves their problem. Also, if this answer solved the problem, please accept it as correct so others will know it worked for you. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/172661) for more information. :-)